# Do transition states violate thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

**Problem:**

Consider the reaction below, with reactants "A" "B" and products "C" "D".

$A + B \rightarrow C + D$

Assume that the spontaneity of this reaction is dictated by the standard Gibb's free energy (N,P,T):

$\Delta G_{rxn}^{0} = \Delta H_{rxn}^{0} - T \Delta S_{rxn}^{0}$

Assume it is indeed spontaneous under standard conditions, such that:

$\Delta G_{rxn}^{0} <= 0$

and

$\Delta G_{C+D}^{0} < \Delta G_{A+B}^{0}$

Transition state theory suggests that there is an activation barrier that must be surpassed to form the products.

[image]

If $\Delta G_{AB\ddagger}^{0} > \Delta G_{A+B}^{0}$, how is the path to the transition state possible?

**Attempt:**

The constraints within the isothermal, isobaric ensemble are (N,P,T). But, the energy and volume of the system are allowed to fluctuate. Therefore, there should exist a small (yet finite) population of molecules within high energy states. As a result, these populations will be capable of "boiling over" to the products. For each product formed, the free energy of the reaction tends to zero; in real time, the reactant's <s>free energy</s> chemical potential decreases whilst the product's <s>free energy</s> chemical potential increases until equilibrium is reached. The height of the activation barrier only dictates the rate of the reaction, but not the spontaneity.

Comment: Thermodynamics and kinetics are separate - one says what the system might like to do, one says what the system can do.

Comment: @JonCuster Can reactions which are thermodynamically "spontaneous" be kinetically hindered such that they do not occur?

Comment: Of course. The classic would be the diamond to graphite transition. Diamonds may be ‘forever’ but they aren’t the stable allotrope at STP.

Comment: @JonCuster In that case would it be correct to say that diamonds do form into graphite at STP, but the activation barrier is so large that the rate is infinitesimal? Given an infinite amount of time, will diamonds exposed to STP eventually form graphite?

Comment: What do you mean by: "For each product formed, the free energy of the reaction tends to zero; in real time, the reactant's free energy decreases whilst the product's free energy increases until equilibrium is reached."? The free energy change and the equilibrium constant of the reaction are concentration independent.

Comment: @Chemomechanics How is $\Delta G_{rxn}$ concentration independent? To simplify the math, consider A->B. The Gibb's free energy change of this reaction at const T,P is $dG_{rxn} = \mu_A dN_A+\mu_B dN_A$ (where $\mu$ is the chemical potential). 

Isn't the equilibrium constant dependent on the ratio of product & reactant concentrations at equilibrium? (Assuming they are an ideal gas)

Honestly, I myself am confused at what I wrote. I think I meant to say "chemical potential" in place of "free energy". Sorry!